# How to configure DHCP with multiple NICs in one subnet?

Tags: linux, router, dhcp, dhcp-server

I want my linux server act as a router.  There are four ethernet ports (eth0, eth1,eth2,eth3) on the server and one wireless card (wlan0).  eth0 is the gateway (WAN), eth1-3 are LAN ports.  How to configure dhcpd to auto assign IP once any device plug into eth1-3?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have search google for a long time, little info could be found about this scenario.  Can you give me some more specific websites?

Comment: Simply bridge them? Why even bother with multiple NICs when you could use a switch?

Comment: Thanks, I just want to learn more about linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a **bridge** between the LAN ports. It's a virtual interface that connects interfaces at Ethernet (MAC) layer, like a switch would. (Commercial home routers usually have a built-in switch to achieve bridging.)

Note that unlike switches, which have a dedicated hardware chip, your bridge will be entirely software-based, meaning that LAN-LAN traffic will also consume CPU.

One manual method of creating a bridge interface on Linux:

```
ip link add br0 type bridge
ip link set br0 up
```

Add some ports:

```
ip link set eth1 master br0
ip link set eth2 master br0
```

*(You'll also find tutorials describing `brctl`; it's a slightly older tool but still achieves the same result.)*

Finally configure IP on br0. Note that the bridged ports (eth1, eth2) themselves *do not* have IP addresses, only the whole bridge (br0) does. So you only need to route between two interfaces, eth0 as WAN and br0 as LAN.

While the manual method is the same everywhere, automatic configuration unfortunately varies between distributions. NetworkManager, netctl, ifupdown, etc. all have bridge support though.

You can use the `bridge` and `brctl` tools to see detailed information about the bridge's internals, e.g. list learned MAC addresses on each port.

Comment: You mean configure DHCP server on br0 and then routing between eth0 and br0?

Comment: Yes. As far as your routing and firewall configuration is concerned, the entire LAN is just that single br0 interface.